# Fastest way to send 2d array of integers via WebSockets?

Tags: python, websocket, bokeh

I have a 256x512 array of integers to send from my Python server to the client via WebSockets. On the client, I plot the 2D image in a canvas. From the server, I am currently doing

```
ws.send(buffer.tobyte(), True)
```

where `buffer` contains the numpy array, but it seems to be slow to reach the client. I tried generating a base64 encoded png but that takes even longer to send to the client. Do I have any faster options, such as send it as serialized JSON instead?

It looks like [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) can do what I'm asking, and they're using WebSockets, but I am still trying to figure out how they do it.

Comment: You won't get faster than `buffer.tobytes()`, unless you compress it on the server and get the client to decompress it

Comment: Bokeh currently serializes to JSON and sends that over the websocket. This is partly historical, since that's the same serialization from before there was a server at all. There are plans (and groundwork laid) for a binary array protocol (basically, `.asbytes` on the numpy array) but that is future work.